SOQL on FieldDefinition object - "LIKE" and "NOT LIKE" Return Same Results?
Somehow, these two logically opposing queries return (almost) the same data.
How in the world do
EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName LIKE '%ChangeEvent%'
and
NOT EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName LIKE '%ChangeEvent%'
both return only data that DOES match '%ChangeEvent%'?
Note that this occurs in both Apex and Dev Console, with or without the Tooling API. My only guess is that the FieldDefinition object itself causes the behavior, and it hasn't been noticed yet.



As per this documentation, the FieldDefinition object Tooling API doesn’t support SOQL operations COUNT(), GROUP BY, LIMIT, LIMIT OFFSET, OR, NOT, and INCLUDES.

The unsupported operations for these objects return errors or
incorrect results.
NOT
Example Query: SELECT qualifiedapiname FROM EntityDefinition WHERE qualifiedapiname!='Account'
Error Returned: Only equals comparisons permitted

So That's why the NOT LIKE and LIKE as the same result.

Thanks for this, really glad to know - but also NO error is thrown at all in the examples above, making this a terribly misleading feature implementation that Salesforce will hopefully fix soon.  Just imagine publishing documentation to say that "NOT" is not supported, and then not only still ALLOWING the use of "NOT", but also returning completely false results, in exactly the same way as if they were correct! After 14 years with Salesforce I don't think I've seen anything quite like it.
